# Multi-tabbed page with multiple modals (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a page that has multiple tabs. In each tab, there is a table and on each row there is a button that opens up a modal. My code works fine as long as only one of my tabs have a modal. However, once I have 2 tabs or more with modals, the content of both tabs will show up on one page, instead of being separated into separate tabs.

Here is my code:

edit-profile.ejs:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
     <li class="active"><a href="#edit1" data-toggle="tab">Edit 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#edit2" data-toggle="tab">Edit 2</a></li>
  </ul>

 <!-- Tab content -->
 <div class="col-xs-9">
                  <!-- Tab panes -->
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="edit1">
                      <div id="edit1">
                        <% include ./partials/edit-profile/_edit1%>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="edit2">
                      <div id="edit2">
                        <% include ./partials/edit-profile/_edit2%>
                      </div>
                    </div>
   <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm">Submit</button></center>
```

In my _edit1.ejs partial, I have:

```
<table id="edit1-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered order-table dt-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User ID</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit1-modal"></span> User 1</td>
      <td>user1@test.com</td>
      <td>Address1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit1-modal"></span> User 2</td>
      <td>user2@test.com</td>
      <td>Address2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div id="edit1-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"> Edit 1 </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <% include ./_edit1-form %>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#edit1-table').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

In _edit2.ejs, I have similar content:

```
<table id="edit2-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered order-table dt-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User ID</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit2-modal"></span> User 1</td>
      <td>user1@test.com</td>
      <td>Address1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit2-modal"></span>User 2</td>
      <td>user2@test.com</td>
      <td>Address2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div id="edit2-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"> Edit 2 </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <% include ./_edit2-form %>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#edit2-table').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

Can anybody help me figure out why my tables are showing up on the same page when both tabs have modals? The modals have different IDs.

Comment: do you have the `<ul class="nav nav-tabs"></ul>` tag ?

Comment: Yes, I have this in my edit-profile.ejs file:

 <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#edit1" data-toggle="tab">Edit 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#edit2" data-toggle="tab">Edit 2</a></li>
 </ul>

Comment: then the problem might be in the bootstrap css and js also jQuery. check this example, it has the right files included : [http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs_dynamic&stacked=h)

Comment: I have all the necessary files included, I just omitted them from this example to keep things short. The tabs work perfectly fine, the modals and/or dataTables are the ones breaking the code.

Comment: so now the tabs work ! what's the problem about modals and tables ?

Comment: once I have 2 tabs or more with modals, the content of both tabs will show up on one page, instead of being separated into separate tabs. If only one tab includes a modal, everything works perfectly fine (each tab shows its own content, dataTables work fine)

Comment: the modal with `id="edit1-modal` needs a closing `div` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, it's working

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
     <li class="active"><a href="#edit1" data-toggle="tab">Edit 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#edit2" data-toggle="tab">Edit 2</a></li>
  </ul>

 <!-- Tab content -->
 <div class="col-xs-9">
                  <!-- Tab panes -->
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    
                   <div class="tab-pane active" id="edit1">
                      <div id="edit1">
                        <table id="edit1-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered order-table dt-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User ID</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit1-modal"></span> User 1</td>
      <td>user1@test.com</td>
      <td>Address1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit1-modal"></span> User 2</td>
      <td>user2@test.com</td>
      <td>Address2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>





<div id="edit1-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"> Edit 1 </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <% include ./_edit1-form %>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-pane" id="edit2">
                      <div id="edit2">
                        <table id="edit2-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered order-table dt-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>User ID</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit2-modal"></span> User 1</td>
      <td>user1@test.com</td>
      <td>Address1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit2-modal"></span> Microsoft</td>
      <td> User 2</td>
      <td>user2@test.com</td>
      <td>Address2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div id="edit2-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"> Edit 2 </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <% include ./_edit2-form %>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
</div>
   <center>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm">Submit</button>
</center>





  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer only uses regular html tables, not the javascript plugin dataTable. Sorry for not being more specific earlier

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin, but I don't see where's the problem. your question was about the tabs not working, in this code snippet it works fine, so adding a plugin is just a matter of adding the css and js links. If you have a problem with dataTable, then that's another question.